# Minimizing $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \; (x_k +1)^{{A/x_k}}$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Consider $ 3 $ positive real numbers such that $ abc = 2 $.

(a) Show that $ f(a,b,c) = \sqrt[a]{a^2+2a+1} + \sqrt[b]{b^2+2b+1} + \sqrt[c]{c^2+2c+1} \geq 9. $

(b) Is there a triple $ (a,b,c) $ satisfying the equality case? If yes, find it. If not, find the minimum of $ f(a,b,c)  $.

Bernoulli's has worked just fine on (a), since $ \require{cancel} (1+a)^{\cancelto{2/a}{bc}} \geq 1 + \cancelto{2}{abc} \Leftrightarrow \sqrt[a]{a^2 + 2a +1} \geq 3 $. However, I could not find the equality case (by guessing-setting $ a=b=c$, of course) or a better minimum of $ f(a,b,c) $.

Moreover, given $ n $ positive real numbers such that $ \displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^{n} x_k  = P > 1, $ can we find the exact minimum of $  \displaystyle {g(n,P) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \; (x_k +1)^{\displaystyle {P/x_k}}} $ and the $n$-tuple that yields that result?

PS: The generic-case answer is more preferable that the $ g(3,2) $ one.

Comment: I find it funny that the expression goes to $e^2+2>9$ as $a\to0$, $b,c\to\infty$.

Comment: Indeed. Also funny that my creative walk after conceiving this problem lead me to think that **limits** could do good.

Do you think that trying **small cases** (perhaps analyze the $ n = 2 $ pattern first) can lead us somewhere?

Comment: Too bad I didn't write explicitly that $e^2+2\approx9.39$, it would have been clear the accepted answer can't be right.

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}(1+a)^{\frac{2}{a}}\geq9$.

Indeed, let $a=\sqrt[3]2e^x$, $b=\sqrt[3]2e^y$ and $c=\sqrt[3]2e^z$.

Hence, $x+y+z=0$ and we need to prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}f(x)\geq0$, where $f(x)=\left(1+\sqrt[3]2e^x\right)^{\frac{\sqrt[3]4}{e^x}}.$

But $f''(x)>0$ for all $x\geq0$, which says that by Vasc's RCF Theorem

it remains to prove our inequality for $y=x$ and $z=-2x$ or
$$2(a+1)^{\frac{2}{a}}+(1+2/a^2)^{a^2}\geq9,$$
which is true and even 
$$2(a+1)^{\frac{2}{a}}+(1+2/a^2)^{a^2}\geq2+e^2$$
is true.

Done!